# Ubuntu switch to newer version of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have python 2.7.6 when installing Ubuntu 14.0.4. I compiled python 2.7.8 from sources:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tgz
tar -xzvf Python-2.7.8.tgz
cd Python-2.7.8
./configure --enable-shared --enable-static
make
sudo make install
```

Then when I typed:

```
 python --version
```

the output is still Python 2.7.6. I want to use python 2.7.8. What am I missing?

Comment: Use a `virtualenv` or `pyenv`; changing the system Python can have serious side effects.

Comment: It will have installed your python binary under `/usr/local/bin`, whereas everything is looking for python at the location `/usr/bin/python`, which is a symlink and therefore easily changeable and revertable. It will be a big risk changing it, as system software may not be tested against that newer version. I say don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, it will install your software's last release.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the previous version from your version and add the new one to your environement.

Comment: How can I add new one to my environment ?